# HttpClientErrorException with spring microservices in java

Tags: java, microservices

I am trying to create 2 microservices. 1st calls 2nd (add method should only check content of review and set approved flag) for approving but I am still receiving an exception `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 null`.

Here you are my REST from 1st microservice

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/addreview", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createReviewForMovie(@RequestBody Review review) {

        ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:9100/add", 
                Boolean.class, review);

        Boolean resultReview = response.getBody();

        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(resultReview, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

And the second one:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody Review review){
    if(review.getReviewContent().length()<10){
        review.setApproved(false);
        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(review.isApproved(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    review.setApproved(true);
    return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(review.isApproved(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How to call 2nd microservice from 1st?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I am using same model class (`Review.class`) with different microservices and this not allow me to execute request.

Add method could not recognize `review` because I pass it from another project.

After my recode it looks like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addreview", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> createReviewForMovie(@RequestBody Review review) {
    Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<String, String>();
    uriVariables.put("reviewContent", review.getReviewContent());
    uriVariables.put("userName", review.getUserName());

    ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:9100/add/{reviewContent}/{userName}", 
            Boolean.class, uriVariables);

    Boolean resultReview = response.getBody();

    return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(resultReview, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{reviewContent}/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> add(@PathVariable("reviewContent") String reviewContent, @PathVariable("userName") String userName){
    if(reviewContent.length()<10){
        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(false, HttpStatus.OK);
    }else if(userName.length()>15){
        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(false, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(true, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

However I am still curious if there is any other way to use `Review.class`.